# How to improve SpringBoot embedded Tomcat startup time

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a SpringMVC app deployed on a Tomcat web server. I tried some optimization to speed up the boot, such as cleaning the web.xml and jar files, removing log files, disabling the defaultTldScan, WebSocket, and JSP. It looks like these optimizations work.

Now I plan to use SpringBoot for my app, how can I optimize the TomCat embedded in SpringBoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cleaning the web.xml

There's no `web.xml` when using embedded Tomcat.

> and jar files

The jar files used are entirely under your control based on the dependencies declared in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`. They should already be pretty minimal by default.

> removing log files

Spring Boot only logs to the console (System.out) by default.

> disabling the defaultTldScan […] and JSP

TLD scanning and JSP support is only enabled if you add a dependency on Jasper.

> disabling […] WebSocket

WebSocket support is enabled if `tomcat-embed-websocket` is on the classpath which it will be if you are using `spring-boot-starter-web`. If you do not want WebSocket support you should exclude this dependency in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`.